# Issue populating ajax response into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What am I missing? I've added the get element by Id and I'm definitely getting a response back, I checked using firebug  and the response is correct. But I can't figure out why it won't populate my div area.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cmdSend").click(function () {
        // Get he content from the input box
        var mydata = document.getElementById("cmdInput").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Terminal/processCommand",
            data: { cmd: mydata },  // pass the data to the method in the Terminal Contoller
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                // we need to update the elements on the page
                document.getElementById("terminal").value = document.getElementById("terminal").value + mydata;
                document.getElementById("terminal").value = document.getElementById("terminal").value + data;
            },
            error: function (e) { alert(e); }
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

And the Div I want the response to be put in:

```
 <div class="terminal" style="overflow:scroll">
 <br>
 </div>
```

Comment: you're using getElementById instead of selecting by class. you're already using JQuery so you can put the result inside the terminal div by doing `$('.terminal').html('SomeData');`

Comment: if you add id="terminal" to that div it might work too lol

Comment: yep...adding ID would work

Comment: Ahhh I completely didn't cop that. I put in the ID but I'm still not getting the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are calling document.getElementById(), but your div does not have an ID of terminal, it has a class called terminal.

Second, you are using jQuery but then switch back to classic JavaScript.  You could update your code to the following:

```
success: function (data) {
     //alert(data);
     // we need to update the elements on the page
     var existingHtml = $(".terminal").html(); 
     $(".terminal").html(existingHtml + mydata + data);
}
```

Note that the `$(".SomeName")` selector is for selecting by class and `$("#SomeName")` is to select by id.

**Edit and Note**

If this terminal div could start to get a lot of data inside of it, you may look at using the `.append()` function in jQuery to prevent having to make a copy of the HTML and overwrite the HTML each time a request is made.  The update would be something similar to the following (its a little shorter and should be more efficient as well)

```
success: function (data) {
     //alert(data);
     // we need to update the elements on the pag
     $(".terminal").append(mydata + data);
}
```

Comment: @ValMangul - awesome, take a look at my edit, I think that it would be an even more efficient method of doing what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Just wondering As there will be a lot of text in this div after long use is there a way of like adding a focusable() type of thing so that as info is appended it looks at the new text

Comment: @ValMangul  There may be a plugin or something you could use.  Look up jquery scrollTo plugins to see if there is something you could use to focus on a specific portion of a div / scroll a div to a location.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to get your element by id, add an id to the div:

```
<div id=terminal class="terminal" style="overflow:scroll">
<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the contend of div not using jquery, you should use innerHTML instead of value.

`document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML + data`